# sort and rank data loaded by the xarray chunks

Tags: netcdf, python-xarray, chunks

I have a .nc (.netCDF) file which sizes at 60+GB. The data array has three dimensions (lon,lat,time).

I am looking to sort the data along the time dimension at each lon,lat. I first read the dataset in chunks, and then sort the sliced data array by the time dimension. But it takes ages in sorting the data, and sorted data does not look right.

Eventually, I will need to add two other dimensions (rank of sorted data, largest get a rank of 1, smallest get the rank of length of the data; the probability of the sorted data, that is probability=1/rank) to the data array and save the output as a .nc file.

My general confusions are,

1. How does the chunks works in xarray, do I have to combine the loaded chunks before manipulation
2. Is there a good approach to deal with the nan values? Skip those grids that are all NaNs.

Here is the code I got so far:

```
import xarray as xr
unit_ds = xr.open_dataset(filename,chunks=1000)
unit_da = unit_ds.dis # dis is the variable name
grid_data = unit_da.sel(lon=-0.05,lat=50.05,method='nearest') # take one lon,lat as an example
sorted_data = grid_data.dropna(dim="time", how="any").sortby("time", ascending=False)
```

Here are what the data looks like.

```
unit_ds
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (time: 14246, lon: 3600, lat: 1500)
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 1980-01-01 1980-01-02 ... 2019-01-01
  * lon      (lon) float64 -179.9 -179.8 -179.8 -179.6 ... 179.8 179.9 180.0
  * lat      (lat) float64 89.95 89.85 89.75 89.65 ... -59.75 -59.85 -59.95
Data variables:
    dis      (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(1000, 1000, 1000), meta=np.ndarray>
Attributes:
    CDI:              Climate Data Interface version 1.9.6 (http://mpimet.mpg...
    history:          Wed May 08 11:42:26 2019: cdo -f nc4 -z zip_9 copy /H07...
    source:           Lisflood output maps
    institution:      European Commission DG Joint Research Centre (JRC)
    Conventions:      CF-1.6
    settingsfile:     /H07_Global/GloFAS/_alfielo/ERA5/output/ERA5_1979-2018/...
    date_created:     Wed Apr  3 18:02:55 2019
    Source_Software:  Lisflood Python
    creator_name:     Peter Burek, A de Roo, Johan van der Knijff
    keywords:         Lisflood, EFAS, GLOFAS
    CDO:              Climate Data Operators version 1.9.6 (http://mpimet.mpg...

unit_da
<xarray.DataArray 'dis' (time: 14246, lat: 1500, lon: 3600)>
dask.array<open_dataset-dis, shape=(14246, 1500, 3600), dtype=float32, chunksize=(1000, 1000, 1000), chunktype=numpy.ndarray>
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 1980-01-01 1980-01-02 ... 2019-01-01
  * lon      (lon) float64 -179.9 -179.8 -179.8 -179.6 ... 179.8 179.9 180.0
  * lat      (lat) float64 89.95 89.85 89.75 89.65 ... -59.75 -59.85 -59.95
Attributes:
    standard_name:   DischargeMaps
    long_name:       ChanQAvg
    units:           m3/s
    esri_pe_string:  GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1...

grid_data
<xarray.DataArray 'dis' (time: 14246)>
dask.array<getitem, shape=(14246,), dtype=float32, chunksize=(1000,), chunktype=numpy.ndarray>
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 1980-01-01 1980-01-02 ... 2019-01-01
    lon      float64 -0.05
    lat      float64 50.05
Attributes:
    standard_name:   DischargeMaps
    long_name:       ChanQAvg
    units:           m3/s
    esri_pe_string:  GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1...

sorted_data
<xarray.DataArray 'dis' (time: 0)>
dask.array<getitem, shape=(0,), dtype=float32, chunksize=(0,), chunktype=numpy.ndarray>
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 
    lon      float64 -0.05
    lat      float64 50.05
Attributes:
    standard_name:   DischargeMaps
    long_name:       ChanQAvg
    units:           m3/s
    esri_pe_string:  GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1...
```

This could be a fairly simple question, but I am new to .netCDF file, any insight will be appreciated.